# T-SQL: convert varchar to numeric

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This might be simple query but I could not get as expected so here to ask. if question is wrong, please do forgive

[image]

On above, I am fetching date field converted to numeric(6), but it is empty so is returning 0. I am trying to use blank space instead of 0

I tried casting like this (I may be wrong):

```
 select 
     isnull(date_disqualified, cast('' as numeric)) as date_disqualified
 from tableA
```

and played with that type of casting numeric to varchar, or int but no luck at all.

Can somebody please help me ,what am I doing wrong or how do I make it work?

This piece made my day:(ANSWER)

```
ISNULL (CAST([date_disqualified] AS VARCHAR(6)), ' ')
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

If you want a blank space, then the entire column needs to be a character.  Basically:

```
select (case when date_disqualified is null then ''
             else convert(varchar(255), date_disqualified, 120)
        end)
```

I'm not sure why you would want to return the value as a number if it is a string.  You should use `convert()` to convert the value to the string that you want.

Comment: because this is done through COBOL program, and I have to set it accordingly,I tried your solution but did not work , error is same as before (Error converting data type varchar to numeric.) because ' ' mean string that I am trying to place in numeric field.

Comment: So, you are trying to store ' ' in numeric field, Is it possible ?

Comment: @BhatiaAshish . . . Sort of.  The SQL Engine converts its it to `0`, which is why that appears in the output.

Comment: @Akka . . . The error is presumably happening in the application where you are reading the data, not in the database.  You cannot read back a blank as a number.